# SQL Server 2008 R2 & Windows Forms Application

Tags: winforms, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I created a local database and a windows form. In the windows form, in the server explorer, I added this database's connection. Now, how can I begin querying it using LINQ-to-SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set up a [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399375.aspx) ?  That is the typical object standing between your LINQ queries and the database connection.

Sample code from the link above:

```
// DataContext takes a connection string. 
DataContext db = new DataContext(@"c:\Northwnd.mdf");

// Get a typed table to run queries.
Table<Customer> Customers = db.GetTable<Customer>();

// Query for customers from London.
var query =
    from cust in Customers
    where cust.City == "London"
    select cust;

foreach (var cust in query)
    Console.WriteLine("id = {0}, City = {1}", cust.CustomerID, cust.City);
```

Comment: I did `DataContext db = new DataContext();`, but I don't know what to put between the parentheses. Apparently, the address of an MDF file, but I don't have one; I can't find the database I created anywhere, yet I can see it in the MSSQL Server 2008 R2 program.

Comment: I just found this: `Data Source=HOUDEVW8L02;Initial Catalog=InventoryTrackingSystem;Integrated Security=True`. It looks like a connection string. Do I put that between the parentheses?

Comment: Follow the link I have included above... it has sample code for the init... but, yes you put the connection in their.  It also has a sample LINQ statement.   Sample from link now in my answer.